# Jackcess decoding not supported warning

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

I'm using Jackcess to help with database connectivity. I have no issues with my program when it's run on my computer and connecting to a database that runs in Access 2013.

I've switched it to another computer now which is using Access 2010 and it's throwing the following error:

```
WARNING:Decoding not supported.  Please choose a CodecProvider which supports reading the current database encoding.
WARNING:Decoding not supported.  Please choose a CodecProvider which supports reading the current database encoding.
```

[Jackess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/faq.html#encoding) suggested I use the Jackcess-encoder. However the database doesn't seem to be encoded in any way, and so I don't think it would do much.

Has anyone else encountered this error?

Comment: If the database is encrypted then you will be prompted for a password when you try to open the database in Access itself. I gather that you don't receive such a prompt on either machine ...?

Comment: Correct. That's the first thing I checked. I would assume that it's some issue with 2010, since it has absolutely no problems with 2013.

Comment: ... except that the version of Access or ACE/Jet, if any, that is installed on a particular machine is completely irrelevant because Jackcess doesn't use the Access Database Engine at all; it operates directly on the .accdb or .mdb file. Where is the database file located? Is each machine trying to open its own local copy of the database file, or is the file on a server share somewhere?

Comment: It's a local file. In one case it's located in the same file as the program (kind of) for ex `c:\users\Eabryt\bot\file.accdb` with the program at `c:\users\Eabryt\bot\src\file.java` In the other case it's more of `c:\users\Eabryt\file.accdb` with the program at `c:users\Eabryt\bot\src\file.java` As far as I know though, that shouldn't be throwing any errors at all, because I give the full path in the java file.

Comment: On the "bad" machine, make a copy of "file.accdb" and call it "bad.accdb". Transfer "bad.accdb" to the "good" machine and have that copy of your Jackcess app try to open "bad.accdb". Does it work?

Comment: Interestingly enough it does seem to throw an error. Not the same error, but instead just a `user lacks privilege or object not found: draftnightquery` even though my version of it still works. I did send my version of the database and while it still gives the codec error, it does seem to update the database. Any ideas on why that might be?

Comment: Have you tried using Access to do a "Compact and Repair Database" on the file(s) to see if that improves the situation?

Comment: No luck. Instead I tried accessing and modifying the information via different tables. Seems to be working on my computer, and logically it should work on the other. I probably won't have access to test that until tonight. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the accepted answer to the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28463234/2144390), this is almost certainly due to corruption of the database file. Even though it was stated in a comment to this question that a "Compact and Repair Database" operation in Access did not fix the problem, the response to the later question indicates that it actually did work.

While the source of the corruption has not yet been firmly established, the fact that the file was being accessed directly from a Dropbox share (as revealed in the later question) is a likely suspect.