# "WARNING:Looking for usage map at page 90566, but page type is 4" and missing table

Tags: ms-access, ucanaccess, jackcess

I've got an Access 2013 database which is supplied by a client. I'm using UCanAccess to read and write from the database. Recently I stopped being able to write to a particular table. When I open the database with DBeaver (which also uses UCanAccess) the table is missing and another is created with the samew name plus 'Tmp' on the end. The new able has the same fields, but is empty.

When I run up my application I also get the error:

"WARNING:Looking for usage map at page 90566, but page type is 4"

in relation to the missing table. When the client opens the same database file with Access on Windows, the table is still there with all the data. Could this be related to:

[Warning: Looking for usage map at page 1774, but page type is 1 in UCanAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463234/warning-looking-for-usage-map-at-page-1774-but-page-type-is-1-in-ucanaccess)

If not what else might cause this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: Looking for usage map at page 1774, but page type is 1 in UCanAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463234/warning-looking-for-usage-map-at-page-1774-but-page-type-is-1-in-ucanaccess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you posted suggests a file may have become corrupted and suggests a possible fix. Did you try that?

Comment: The client tried the fix and compact and it fixed the issue.