# Ucanaccess 4.0.3 cannot find a specific table in my DB

Tags: ucanaccess

I'm using jdbc with ucanaccess... When I connect to the database, there is one table that Ucanaccess is not finding... I saw that in debug mode in NetBeans...

Therefore when I try a transaction on that table, I get :

> UCAExc:::4.0.3 user lacks privilege or object not found [Name of my table]

I guess everything else works perfectly since when I did a `select` on another table it worked...

I'm using :

- ucanaccess 4.0.3
- MS Access 2007
- JDK : java 1.8.0_151
- Netbeans : NetBeans IDE 8.2

**Update**

When Opening the database with console.bat ( by the way, this file is located in UcanAccess download folder) I got the follwoing warnings/errors :

> WARNING:Looking for usage map at page 9093, but page type is 1
>
> Cannot load procedure Query4 user lacks privilege or object not found: [My Table Name]
>
> Cannot resolve table [My Table Name]

Comment: Try opening the database file using console.bat or console.sh and see if you get any warnings about that table.

Comment: @GordThompson Awesome tip... I Did not know about `console.bat`... I did it and I wrote the messages in my OP... My table, though present in Access, is not among the tables loaded by `console.bat`

Comment: Sounds like your database file might be slightly damaged. Make a backup for safety and then open it in Access and try doing a Compact and Repair Database on it.

Comment: @GordThompson Yes!!! This solved the issue. Everything works fine now... May I ask how you figured this out from the info I gave you ? Also you can add this as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: Looking for usage map at page 1774, but page type is 1 in UCanAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463234/warning-looking-for-usage-map-at-page-1774-but-page-type-is-1-in-ucanaccess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> WARNING:Looking for usage map at page 9093, but page type is 1

strongly suggests a damaged database file. Jackcess, the record manager used by UCanAccess, retrieved a page (block) of data from the file expecting it to be tagged as a "usage map" but it was tagged as something else.

The most common solution for a damaged database file is to open it in Access and then do a "Compact and Repair Database" operation on it.

Comment: Thank You. It works fine now. Please vote my question up if you think it may help someone else...